# Laravel 5: Missing Argument Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am calling the EventController with the action() from my navbar:

```
<a href="{{ action('EventController@list_events',['host_id' => Auth::user()->host_id]) }}">
```

In the EventController:

```
public function list_events($host_id)
    {
        $events = 'Hallo';
        return view('list_events',['$events' => $events]);
    }
```

And when I open it in the browser the following error occurse:

> ErrorException in EventController.php line 60: Missing argument 1 for
>   App\Http\Controllers\EventController::list_events()

Comment: show your routes file

Comment: Route::get('/list_events','EventController@list_events')->middleware('auth');

Comment: see answer of Alexey, you need to edit you route 
`/list_events/{host_id}` instead of `/list_events`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route to:

```
Route::get('list_events/{host_id}', 'EventController@list_events')->mi‌​ddleware('auth');
```